# In app request for privilege escalation C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, uac

I have an application that under rare circumstances needs to change its registry setting.  Also during it's first execution it needs to create a new key.  I'm developing this in Windows 7.  I get ThrowUnauthorizedAccessException.  How do I force Windows to give me a UAC prompt to temporarily elevate my permissions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't elevate the permissions of an already existing process. You need to spawn a new process with higher permissions.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Bummer.  I was really hoping this was possible.

Comment: The problem is that the privilege level doubles as integrity level. But to support secure elevation of already running processes, that process would need an integrity level of the highest level it might elevate to. Else an untrusted other process might manipulate your process while you're still running with a low integrity/permission level.

Comment: Could you install the application with an installer (e.g. using WiX), and create the reg key at install time? You could also assign write permissions at the same time.

Comment: @PaulNearney Yeah I'm going to fall back on creating reg key at install time if I have to.  The specific case I wanted to support was updating the path file in a reg key if the user moved the application.

Comment: Now i'm intrigued ;o) Why would a user move the application?

Comment: @PaulNearney Haha, yeah.  I've seen users do weirder and more bizarre things.

Comment: Really, i'd be tempted to let the users know that if they move the application, all bets are off. I'm not convinced that developers should be creating self-healing apps like that. Unless there's a requirement, or a strong case to be made for doing that, that i'm overlooking?

Comment: I agree with you completely.    I'm not spending any further time trying to protect the user from himself/herself.

Comment: Did you come to a conclusion regarding the issue? If so either answer or close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should all users be allowed to modify this setting? If so, the simplest solution is to modify your installation program to give **Users** `Full Control` of the registry key.

If only administrators should be able to modify this setting, then you will need to launch another copy of your program, asking Windows to elevate it:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Path\To\MyApplication.exe");

startInfo.Verb = "runas"; //trigger a UAC prompt (if UAC is enabled)

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

If you were smart you would include some command line arguments, so you can tell "yourself" that it should jump straight to the part of the software that the user needs to deal with. Or your command line arguments could just say *what* you want done:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
      "C:\Path\To\MyApplication.exe", 
      "/setLoggingEnabled yes");

startInfo.Verb = "runas"; //trigger a UAC prompt (if UAC is enabled)       

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Have your application check for the `setLoggingEnabled` switch, make the change, and then exit.

**Update**: A common situation is players of **World of Warcraft**. Since the game is allowed to update itself while running, **all users** must be allowed to modify the game data sitting in `Program Files`. The *correct and valid* action is to modify the ACLs on the

```
C:\Program Files\Blizzard\World of Warcraft
```

folder so that all users have full control. In fact, before Blizzard got their act together, Microsoft released an application compatibility update that gives all users full control to the WoW folder next time it run as an administrator.

Another common case is when the **Blizzard Launcher** is launched with administrative privelages, it updates a registry key in HKLM, recording *where* the game is. This happens when, for example, i move WoW from a hard drive to an SSD drive

run the launcher once as an administator so that the updaters work correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  This is as close to an answer as any I've seen.